# Unable to group by() and sum() in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this dataframe where I have multiple PatientID because of different visits. I am trying to calculate sum of refills per Patient regardless of the visit

My data looks like this

```
PatientID   refills_auth
000BE424-54C2   0
000BE424-54C2   0
000BE424-54C2   0
000BE424-54C2   1
000BE424-54C2   1
0011A43B-9638   0
0011A43B-9638   0
0011A43B-9638   0
0011A43B-9638   0
0011A43B-9638   1
0011A43B-9638   1
0011A43B-9638   0
0011A43B-9638   0
0011A43B-9638   0
0011A43B-9638   0
0011A43B-9638   0
0011A43B-9638   0
0011A43B-9638   0
0011A43B-9638   0
0011A43B-9638   3
0011A43B-9638   0
0011A43B-9638   0
0011A43B-9638   0
0011A43B-9638   0
0011A43B-9638   0
0011A43B-9638   0


InfoScrbRefSum.groupby(['PATID']).sum().groupby('PATID').sum()
```

and the result looks like this

```
PatientID   refills_auth
000BE424-54C2    00011
0011A43B-9638    1000011000000...
```

Some of the Sum are populated correctly others are not - Here is what I get for some rows

Any help is highly appreciated

Thanks
[image]
  [image][image]

Comment: whats the reasoning for the double group by/sum?

Comment: "Some of the Sum are populated correctly others are not" is vague. What output do you expect exactly?

Comment: Please see the attached screenshot for clarification

Comment: I used   `df.groupby(['PatientID']).sum()`, and I got lot of NAN and wrong sum

Comment: I added two snapshots of the result I got using `InfoScrbRefSum.groupby(['PatientID']).sum().groupby('PatientID').sum()` and `InfoScrbRefSum.groupby(['PatientID']).sum()`

Comment: There is no complete data. Can you paste little more as the attached image & pasted **DataFrame** both have different data. In my case, I'm getting correct o/p using `df = df.groupby("PatientID").sum()`.

Comment: Adding a 3rd screenshot as requested - circled data was not populated correct

Comment: I think the column `refills_auth` is a string and not int. that is why sum just adds each elements(str concat) intead of sum, convert it using `refills_auth=refills_auth.astype(int)` and it should work fine.